# Django Celery write to database task from node blocking occasionally

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, rabbitmq, celery

I have an application which is taking a csv file via an upload view, it reads the data from the file into a list, then passes the list to a celery task, the task then uses a generator function to split the data into chunks of 200 (with a bit of pre-processing to ensure there are no duplicates). These chunks are then passed to a task set, to process chunks and write lines to the database, the subtask then passes results of lines written etc to the main task to record a log of the full taskset.

I am getting a problem when loading large sets of data that 1 task writing a chunk of 200 lines to the database randomly freezes, if I kill this task then the queue continues to process. This never happened when testing with the db and celery running locally, so I am assuming it is some kind of mysql connection problem, celery.log and mysql logs are not revealing anything and due to my lack of experience I am not entirely sure how to troubleshoot it.

I am running django, mysql, rabbitmq for task queue and results with 1 server for db, webserver and another for task processing (2 x AWS EC2 running ubuntu server 12.04).

My code:

```
#views.py

reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['f'], delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
#Skip the header
reader.next()
uploaddata = [row for row in reader]

LegacyUploadManager.delay(uploaddata, log.pk)

#tasks.py

class LegacyUploadManager(Task):
    """
    Task to take uploads, split into smaller tasks and manage
    """
    def run(self, f, logpk):
        #Create chunk generator to split chunks into sets of 200
        ChunkGen = UploadChunkGen(f, 200)
        #Generate chunks and create a taskset of chunk tasks
        self.tasks = []
        for chunk in ChunkGen:
            self.tasks.append(LegacyUploader.subtask([chunk]))
        #create taskset and start processing
        job = TaskSet(self.tasks)
        result = job.apply_async()
        #Wait for tasks to complete
        while result.waiting():
                time.sleep(10)
        #Write results to database via ImportLogger task
        ImporterLogger.delay(logpk, result.join())


class LegacyUploader(Task):
    """
    Task for uploading products imported from ESP via a full product layout.
    """
    def run(self, f):

        for row in f:
            Product.objects.create(row)
```

I think I just need to add 'timeout=....' param to my 'job.apply_async()' but I am not sure of the consequences of doing this. I.e. will I lose all lines not processed on the timed out task or will lines written to the database before the task timed out be written again?

Comment: do you use django-celery ?

Comment: Yes it is django-celery I am using

Comment: take a look at the following - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=innodb#mysql-is-throwing-deadlock-errors-what-can-i-do